# manage maven different cglib/asm versions

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, sandbox, cglib

I have a multi-module project in maven, that uses (amongst others) `glassfish-jersey`, `jersey-moxy`, `wicket-ioc`, `lucene` and `lamdbaj` These all come with `asm`, but all with different versions.
Lately, I run into a lot of trouble when running my tests. Typical error I get is:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

I read that this can be caused by different `asm` versions. Is there a way to 'sandbox' these different asm-versions in their dependencies, so they don't get mixed up?

Edit:

My current solution is to use `jarjar`, like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jarjar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jarjar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>cglib:cglib-nodep</include>
              </includes>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <pattern>net.sf.cglib.asm.**</pattern>
                  <result>com.myproject.lambda4j.asm.@1</result>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                  <pattern>net.sf.cglib.**</pattern>
                  <result>com.myproject.lambda4j.cglib.@1</result>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: This is precisely why the ASM developers themselves tell you that you should repackage asm into your own namespace rather than depending on it directly ([FAQ #15](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q15)) as it's not guaranteed to be compatible across versions.  I'd be tempted to report this as a bug in Jersey, Lucene, etc.

Comment: People usually use cglib without understanding that it uses ASM under the covers. Cglib does not come with such a warning, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly adding some cglib v3.* on your class path which uses [a recent version of ASM](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=cglib/cglib/3.1/cglib-3.1.pom). The problem that you encounter is that cglib modifies the behavior of the ASM class writer by inheritance rather then by delegation. However, ASM enforced this latter best practice by making its `ClassWriter`'s methods `final` [from any version 4.*](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) while it was still possible to override its methods [in version 3](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html). The error you encounter is a result of combining cglib 2.* with ASM 4.*.

Fortunately (for you), cglib has been rather static in its last versions, i.e. there were only minor API changes while the newer versions mostly consisted of updates of ASM. If you are lucky, this explicit use of cglib v3.* therefore solves your problem. This holds as long as none of your project dependencies has a direct dependency on ASM what seems reasonable for the dependencies you named like Jersey or Lucene.

If this does not work, you need to recompile some of your dependencies while using a tool like *jarjar* in order to repack the direct ASM dependencies into different name spaces in order to resolve these version conflicts. An alternative could be to isolate different ASM versions by some conditional child-first `ClassLoader` magic but this is not so recommendable since the effects are unpredictable and will also result in a performance penalty.

Comment: Dropping in cglib 3.1 and excluding the cglib dependencies from the other projects seems do to the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Alas, the problem is solved under Jenkins and in my Linux environment; but the Windows people seems to still suffer from it.

Comment: That should not make a difference of what ends up on the class path. I guess that your Windows people might use another IDE for running the application on the fly. I guess there something is added to the class path by the IDE. Check the class path for any cglib 2.2 dependency on one of the Windows machines. I guess there is some class path caching involved. When using IntelliJ, reimport all Maven projects. When using Eclipse, use IntelliJ.

Comment: Currently I'm repackaging libs usign JarJar. It seems the only stable solution this far. Thanks for the support!